# Tensorflowlite on android buffer size error

Tags: android, python-3.x, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

Im trying to build a image classifier android app. I've built my model using keras.
The model is as follows:

```
model.add(MobileNetV2(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.layers[0].trainable = False     
model.compile(optimizer='adam',  loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
mobilenetv2_1.00_224 (Functi (None, 7, 7, 1280)        2257984   
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_2 ( (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 3843      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,261,827
Trainable params: 3,843
Non-trainable params: 2,257,984
```

After training Im converting the model using

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open(f"myModel.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

for android the code is as:

```
        make_prediction.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            var resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224, true)
            val model = MyModel.newInstance(this)
            var tbuffer = TensorImage.fromBitmap(resized)
            var byteBuffer = tbuffer.buffer

// Creates inputs for reference.
            val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 224, 224, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
            inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
            val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
            val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

            var max = getMax(outputFeature0.floatArray)

            text_view.setText(labels[max])

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
            model.close()
        })
```

but whenever i try to run my app it closes and i get this error in the logcat.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The size of byte buffer and the shape do not match.
```

if I change the input shape of my image to 300 from 224 and train my model on 300 input shape and plug in to android I get anthor error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 1080000 bytes and a Java Buffer with 150528 bytes
```

Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you create TensorBuffer.createFixedSize? var byteBuffer will be OK to be processed from model. Like val outputs = model.process(byteBuffer) . Check it and get back if it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it like:

```
make_prediction.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            var resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 224, 224, true)
            val model = MyModel.newInstance(this)
            var tImage = TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32)
            var tensorImage = tImage.load(resized)
            var byteBuffer = tensorImage.buffer

// Creates inputs for reference.
            //val inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(intArrayOf(1, 224, 224, 3), DataType.FLOAT32)
            //inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer)

// Runs model inference and gets result.
            val outputs = model.process(byteBuffer)
            val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer

            var max = getMax(outputFeature0.floatArray)

            text_view.setText(labels[max])

// Releases model resources if no longer used.
            model.close()
        })
```

Then check with debugger if the problem persists or

`val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer`
causes another one.

Ping me if you need more help